О запятой между однородными придаточными в СПП
Из переводной литературы:
Но если время, как тиран кровавый,
К упадку нас уверенно ведет(,)
И мы всегда виновны и бесправны,
То можно ли нарушить его ход?
Насколько корректна здесь запятая? В общем случае запятая в СПП не должна ставиться, но без запятой стих выглядит странно. А тогда как ее объяснить, или требуется другое оформление?
Весь текст:
 Но если время, как тиран кровавый,
 К упадку нас уверенно ведет,
 И мы всегда виновны и бесправны,
 То можно ли нарушить его ход?

 На высоте годов, где счастлив ты,
 Так много еще девственных садов
 И много неподдельной красоты
 Живых цветов, что ты принять готов.

 Исправить можешь времени черты 
 Ты сам, не  мой учебный  карандаш,
 Когда  подарки щедрые судьбы
 Добру и справедливости отдашь.

 Останешься во времени любом,
 Влекомый своим милым мастерством.

Правильны ли остальные знаки, в том числе во второй строфе?

Но если время, как тиран кровавый,
К упадку нас уверенно ведет,
И мы всегда виновны и бесправны,
То можно ли нарушить его ход?
Я предполагаю, что у автора это СПП, в котором выделенная часть является вставкой.

3. В редких случаях вставная конструкция выделяется запятыми: Мне показалось даже, а может быть оно и в самом деле было так, что все стали к нам ласковее (Акс.)... [Розенталь]

На высоте годов, где счастлив ты,
Так много еще девственных садов
И много неподдельной красоты
Живых цветов, что ты принять готов.
Здесь, мне кажется, всё в порядке с пунктуацией.
"Упростим": На высоте годов так много садов и много красоты живых цветов.
Исправить можешь времени черты
Ты сам, не  мой учебный  карандаш,
Когда  подарки щедрые судьбы
Добру и справедливости отдашь.
Во избежание двусмысленности я бы заключила отмеченную часть в скобки.

Римма, большое спасибо за ответ. Мне нравится ваш вариант анализа со вставными конструкциями.  Думаю, во второй части стиха вставку также можно обособить запятыми, а не скобками. Дело в том, что у этих знаков разная выделительная способность, и в данном случае достаточно именно запятых.
